# Cheesecake Reincarnation

Tags: baking, dessert, cheesecake, mistakes

I significantly over-baked my cheesecake today (I forgot to check the temp extra early to compensate for the fact that there was a baking stone in the oven).  Now I'm trying to decide if it is possible or worth pursuing  trying to reincarnate the cheesecake into something else.  My first idea is to mix it with whipped cream to make a filling to pipe into lace cookie trumpets/cones.  I'd appreciate any insights into turning a cheesecake into a cheesecake filling or any other ideas of how to repurpose an over-baked cheesecake.

Comment: How badly over-baked are we talking? If it's not too bad, you can save it as a cheesecake by adding a topping, such as whipped creme; strawberry or raspberry sauce; chocolate; caramel; etc.

Comment: Bake or prepare something else, then incorporate it as an enhancement, e.g., like between cookies in an Oreo fashion, or as a thin layer between cake sheets. It's probably too dry to be the primary.

Comment: You might be able to whip some cream into it and call it cannoli filling?

Answer (score 1):

Add it in pieces to an ice cream after it is done freezing in the ice cream maker but before putting it in the freezer to harden.

Answer (score 0):

Slice off the dark layer at the top and check the texture of the cheesecake beneath. That should give you an idea of what you can do to salvage the filling.

Comment: What should the author be looking for, and how should they proceed from there?